# Streaming write into csv file

Tags: java, csv, bufferedoutputstream, apache-utils

I need generate report of some big amount of data into csv file. I want avoid loading all data into memory and flush them all. My preferable way is create csv header and next in sequence write data into csv.

I'm using csv printer of apache csv which can create csv line with some settings. But when I call after every write flush writing is too slow.

Do you have any advice how to solve that task?

Comment: What is wrong with streaming a certain number of bytes at a time, and then writing to file?

Comment: Wh note call flush() after any 10th or 100th write then?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I am not sure if I can do that with csv printer of apache library.

Comment: Use a `new BufferedWriter(...)` or [`Files.newBufferedWriter(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newBufferedWriter-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.charset.Charset-java.nio.file.OpenOption...-)

Answer (score 1):

## `BufferedWriter`

Java offers the [`BufferedWriter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/BufferedWriter.html) class to automatically handle efficient writing to storage. No need for you to call [`flush`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/Flushable.html#flush()). You can set the size of the buffer, but I suggest you start by using the default size.

A convenient way to instantiate such a object is by calling [`Files.newBufferedWriter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#newBufferedReader(java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.charset.Charset)).

Base your [`CSVPrinter`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/apidocs/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVPrinter.html) object on the `BufferedWriter`.